# Getting data with substr dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, substring

I've got this data:

```
204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|
```

I want to extract the number after the colon on each of the bigger numbers, I can get a single number but when getting more than a double character number such as 11 I have to increase the substring range, now if I do that for 6 for example, it will display '6|' how do I make it so the substr will get the number no matter what length the number is?

Comment: Can you provide us with your current code so we can spot the issue?

Comment: Why not using `explode`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a good example that shows why you shouldn't use length related functions with numbers related content.

`explode` would work perfectly with your given input though :

```
$str = "204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|";
$str_array = explode ('|', $str);
foreach ($str_array as $sub_str) {
   echo explode(':', $sub_str)[1]; // EDIT : Ok you wanted the part AFTER ':' I guess, so [1].
}
```

As notified by @PraveenKumar and @hindmost, this syntax works since PHP 5.5

On previous versions, you could use :

```
$str = "204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|";
$str_array = explode ('|', $str);
foreach ($str_array as $sub_str) {
   $tmp =  explode(':', $sub_str); 
   echo $tmp[1];
}
```

Comment: array dereferencing (`explode(':', $sub_str)[1]`) is only available since PHP 5.5

Comment: @PraveenKumar On most recent PHP versions, it does. By default as the PHP version is not given, I assume it's the last one.

Comment: More concise yet compatible version:
`array_map(function ($v) {
 return count($a = explode(':')) >= 2? $a[1] : $v;
}, explode('|', $array));`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this with substring. You need to use `explode()` for this:

```
$data = "204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|";
$data = explode("|", $data);
```

The above splits in the first level, and gives you an array with items:

```
204:7
209:8
210:10
```

And the next one, you need to use:

```
foreach ($data as $cData)
{
    $num = explode(':', $cData);
    echo $num[1];
}
```

Comment: This is for a phone system so, how would I map the amount that say 209 has to specific person, and there will be more phone numbers in that list. So the list will constantly change.

Comment: I have answered my own question, I did an array_search to search for my phone number, then exploded that to get the amount of calls. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `explode` function to break this string into array. Your code should look like this

```
 <?php
        $sting = "204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|";
        $explode = explode ('|', $str);
        foreach ($explode as $test) {
          echo $test;
        }
?>
```

OR if you want the number after `:`

```
<?php
        $sting = "204:7|209:8|210:10|211:11|220:1|225:6|226:5|";
        $explode = explode ('|', $str);
        foreach ($explode as $test) {
          echo explode(":",$test)[1];
        }
?>
```

Hope this helps you